# Pass php object to different script in magento

Tags: php, object, magento, attributes

I have a php script that's called in by xml to show on the product page as a tab.

I need to be able to to retrieve the attributes of the current product shown in the script as well.
for example:

```
<?php echo $_product->getSKU() ?>
```

Does any one have any idea how to pass the object, or retrieve the current products ID/attributes?

Thanks so much

Comment: The product page already has a template that shows the attributes. Are you using a non-default theme?

Comment: What block type you are using in layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `json_encode($object)` to output to JSON and `json_decode($text)` to put it back as an object later. There are other way, depending what you wanna do. Be more specific?

Comment: I need to retrieve the products attributes, in a script thats not part of the products page but gets called, and then shows on the products page.

Comment: Then I think that should work. You can output the JSON to a file, or just as a text variable or whatever you need.